# Problem with $_GET / $_POST when passing variable from Javascript popup to parent window to use in PHP MySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, popup, parent-child

The flow chart of my end goal is essential:

> 1. Click the "add" button in the parent window ---> Popup window showing a list to choose an item from.
> 2. The user clicks a row from the list & submits that item as an index/ID.
> 3. Popup / Child window closes and the variable is passed back to the parent window.
> 4. Parent window can use that variable in PHP to query the item ID in MySQL and add the data into a new row.

The parent window is also always open during this process, so I used `window.onunload` of the child window to trigger the SQL query.

First of all, I understand from similar posts that JS is client-side while PHP is server-side, so it's possible to get a PHP variable in JS using `<? php echo ?>`, but not the other way around, at least directly.

I used `form.submit()` to send the data back to the parent window via `POST` method through a form. However, `isset($_POST['itemID']` turns up false, as the predefined value I set for `$full_id` is still 1.

Child Window

```
var txt = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");

txt.value = "1chosen";      
var submit = window.opener.document.getElementById("submit");
submit.value = str;


document.getElementById('myID').value = str;

var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.submit();


window.close();


}

window.onunload = function (e) {
    
    opener.somefunction(); //or
    }
;



    </script>

</body>

<form action="/combine-quote.php" id="myForm" method="get">
  <input id="myID" name="itemID"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Parent Window

```
window.somefunction = function(){

var choice = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
var id = document.getElementById('submit').value;

if (choice =="1chosen"){

    if (id != ""){

        <?php
            $xd=1;
            $full_id = "1";
            if (isset($_GET['itemID'])){
            $full_id=$_GET['itemID'];
            }


        ?>

            alert(<?php echo $full_id; ?>);

    }
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['itemID'] turns up false`...where are you running that? I don't see it in your code. Please provide a [mre] of the issue including all relevant code. And please format your code with proper indentation so it's easily readable. Thanks.

Comment: But since you submit the form with `method="get"`, it won't provide any POST values in any case.

Comment: If you're wanting to get a value from the URL with JavaScript (such as would be submitted as a parameter in a GET request), you actually don't need PHP for that.

Comment: Is your original parent window (where you pressed 'add') reloading when the values are sent? You can't dynamically modify php values, a reload needs to happen

Comment: If you don't want the parent window to reload you can use [AJAX](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-ajax.php). In that case the child window should call a Javascript function in the parent window, to retrieve the new row from the PHP script and put it in the HTML table.